# How to take macro pictures using any smart phone camera?

Tags: technology, phone, photography

Is there any way of taking close up photos with a camera phone?

Are there any life hacks to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically what you need is a small lens to magnify your existing camera lens to take some close up macro. Then hold the lens over your camera lens and viola.

This is what you need:

1. Extract small lens from old DVD player/burner, a disposable camera or just take apart a cheap laser pointer.

   [image: Old DVD Player]
   [image: In order to take macro pictures you need that lens (in the middle)]
2. Mount your lens either by using some duct tape and [Blu-Tack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blu-Tack) or put it between hair clamp and use tape to secure it from moving.

   [image: use some duct tape to mount your lens directly, use or blue Tack to hold the card mount]
   [image: put that macro lens between hair clamp and used Macgyver's tape to secure it from moving]
   [image: as a macro lens for iPhone, Image credits: Photographs by Zaheer Mohiuddin]
3. Now you can take some awesome close up macro pictures.

   [image: macro bubbles]
   [image: macro euro cent]
   [image: macro sugar]
   [image: macro pictures of trees with HTC]
   [image: macro electronics]
   [image: macro note]

---

Sources/links:

- [Super macro your cellphone camera with a DVD lens](http://www.diyphotography.net/super-macro-your-cellphone-camera-with-a-dvd-lens/) at Diy Photography
- [How to build cheap macro lens with Cheap lazer, Hair clamp, Tape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nyNAl.jpg)
- [Turn a DVD Lens into a Cellphone Macro Lens Redux](http://lifehacker.com/5616044/turn-a-dvd-lens-into-a-cellphone-macro-lens-redux) at Life hacker
- [Turn a Cheap Laser Pointer Into a Removable Macro Photography Lens for Your Phone](http://lifehacker.com/5943363/turn-a-cheap-laser-pointer-into-a-removable-macro-photography-lens-for-your-phone) at Life hacker
- [Take amazing Macro pics with any camera phone camera... especially an iPhone](http://www.instructables.com/id/Take-amazing-Macro-pics-with-any-camera-phone-came/) by livingdog
- [Find a $1 Macro Lens for Your Phone Inside a Cheap Laser Pointer](http://petapixel.com/2012/08/12/find-a-1-macro-lens-for-your-phone-inside-a-cheap-laser-pointer/) at PetaPixel

Comment: How does this not flummox the auto-focus?